# Cannot find "Help -> Install New Software" option in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Why don't I have the "Install New Software" option? How do I enable it again?

Comment: Which download is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it as administrator displays the options for adding new plugins. I'd consider this a workaround at best.